# Adding columns with two data types in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I need to achieve the output like this can anyone please help me. Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: This violates 1NF (first normal form) for 2 reasons I can think of.  1) You should not have multiple datatypes, and/or values representing different things, within the same column.  2) You should not have to 'unpack' data in order to access values in the column.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `left()` & `right()` function if your data format will always in specified format

```
select LEFT(names, 1) [name], SUM(cast(right(names, 2) as int)) [sum] from <table>
group by LEFT(names, 1)
```

Comment: wont work for the given data. cast error. took the liberty to fix it up in my answer and cite yours.

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
declare @tab table (names varchar(1000))
insert into @tab
select 'a10' union select 'abc20' union select 'xyz5' union select 'b6'

select * from @tab

select names, substring(names, 1, patindex('%[0-9]%',names)-1) [name], substring(names, patindex('%[0-9]%',names), len(names)) [sum]
from @tab
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function like

`Create Function dbo.GetNumbers(@Data VarChar(8000))
Returns VarChar(8000)
AS
Begin

    Return Left(
             SubString(@Data, PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%', @Data), 8000), 
             PatIndex('%[^0-9.-]%', SubString(@Data, PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%', @Data), 8000) + 'X')-1)
End`

Source [Solved Already](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/extracting-numbers-with-sql-server/)

If you want more control (multiple numbers in a string) would be better to create a CLR function.

---

Use below T-SQL to get aggregated results without function:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #splitString
    CREATE TABLE #splitString(
    [columnA] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [columnB] [nchar](10) NULL) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT #splitString ([columnA], [columnB]) VALUES (N'a10', NULL)
GO
INSERT #splitString ([columnA], [columnB]) VALUES (N'a05', NULL)
GO
INSERT #splitString ([columnA], [columnB]) VALUES (N'b20', NULL)
GO
INSERT #splitString ([columnA], [columnB]) VALUES (N'a5', NULL)
GO
INSERT #splitString ([columnA], [columnB]) VALUES (N'b9', NULL)
GO


select * from #splitString
select a,sum(b) from (
select 

             Left(
             SubString([columnA], PatIndex('%[a-z.-]%', [columnA]), 8000), 
             PatIndex('%[^a-z.-]%', SubString([columnA], PatIndex('%[a-z.-]%', [columnA]), 8000) + 'X')-1) a,
             cast (Left( SubString([columnA], PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%', [columnA]), 8000), 
             PatIndex('%[^0-9.-]%', SubString([columnA], PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%', [columnA]), 8000) + 'X')-1) as int) b
From #splitString )aTable group by a
```

**Explanation (Thanks the external link person)**

1. Get the first character that is int (PatIndex(‘%[0-9.-]%’, Data))
2. Remove all characters left to int (SubString(Data, PatIndex(‘%[0-9.-]%’, Data), 8000))
3. Find end of numbers (Select PatIndex(‘%[^0-9.-]%’, SubString(Data, PatIndex(‘%[0-9.-]%’, Data)+1, 8000)) )
4. Get all ints - (Select Left(SubString(Data, PatIndex(‘%[0-9.-]%’, Data), 8000), PatIndex(‘%[^0-9.-]%’, SubString(Data, PatIndex(‘%[0-9.-]%’, Data), 8000) + ‘X’)-1))
5. Repeat above procedure for strings.

Comment: This function does not solve the problem of Splitting + Grouping  as asked by the question, uses ridicules amounts of VarChar and contains an offsite link that you should at least summarize in case it gets vanished somewhen.You solved part of the problem (the splitting) - but that alone is no answer to this question.

Comment: @PatrickArtner i have edited this based on your observations, and I would love to see an easier solution using SQL server.

Comment: I fixed @YogeshSharmas error in my answer and converted yours to a simpler form - no function needed, lots less padindexes and no substrings in between to speed it up. Things I think you should think about fixing: Yours splits at `.-`  for numbers and digits which was not asked for, your column names do not fit. Lots of padindex as well as substrings tend to slow down statements considerably when used in large data sets. Removed my -1 though - yours works now.No +1 from me because its way complexer than needed to solve the issue at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Sql (works even for "a5" - Yogesh Sharma (https://stackoverflow.com/a/47727953/7505395) did the hard work, I fixed it):

```
select 
  left(names,1) as name, 
  sum(cast( right(names,len(names)-1) as int)) 
from t
group by left(names,1)
```

---

Testdata:

```
CREATE TABLE t ( names  varchar(30));     
INSERT INTO t  ( names ) VALUES ('a10'), ('b20'), ('a5'), ('b6');
```

Result:

```
name    sum
a       15
b       26
```

If you need more then one character in front you can do this:

```
select 
    left(n,idxFirstNum-1) as name, 
    sum(cast(right(n,len(n)-idxFirstNum+1) as int)) as sum
from (
  select 
    names as n,
    PatIndex('%[0-9]%', names) as idxFirstNum  
  from t
) as tmp 
group by left(n,idxFirstNum-1)
```

which will store the index of the first digit on each name in an inner tableselect and then cast/sum/group it in the outer select.